Getting "org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: " when trying to call a remote feature file which perfectly works when run alone
I am having the below error while trying to call another feature file which will launch the Splunk UI to capture a accessToken and returns to my feature where I am going to use that token to run my scenario outline.
Below is my Calling Feature file from where I am trying to call the F_CustomerID feature file which has the UI code to run as the background task.

Below is the caller feature file which launches the browser to capture the token and save it to accessToken

Problem here is, when I run the Caller feature file (F_CustomerID.feature), this runs perfectly fine and able to capture the access token and return it.
However when I try to call the F_CsutomerID.feature from my API_Capture feature file, I am getting the below error. It's not able to retreive the values from the karate-config.js. I am not sure what's the wrongdoing here and would really need some help to understand/resolve this issue.

Below is my Karate-config.js file screenshot

And below is the runner file

Below are the Environment details :
Karate-Core 1.5.0
Karate-JUnit5 1.5.0
Java 17
And to add to the list, Though I tried using callSingle, callonce to keep the calling to single time, it still triggers as many number of times as my Example table has.

sorry, this is a case where you have to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - please also be aware of stack overflow guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Thank you Peter, I will follow the process and submit a ticket. And Sorry If I didn't follow the Guidelines properly while posting the question. I will revisit and correct myself next time.
